# Context variables in Watson Assistant

Tags: ibm-cloud, chatbot, watson-assistant

What could be the issue: trying to set a passthrough node in Watson Assistant for a chat bot dialog skill. As setting context variable $city the system defines it as an invalid.

Comment: Provide more details, it is not clear what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Due to your message, I think that you are using the context editor UI. If that is the case, you must not use the `$` sign in the variable input box; just write `city` as variable name